# Generic props for React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `Linechart` component

```
<LineChart />
```

This component should take two props `xField` and `yField` both strings. For this I create the prop type

```
type Props = {
    xField: string;
    yField: string;
}
// e.g <LineChart xField="Date" yField="EUR"/>
```

This component should also take an array of data points (an object with two keys), example:

```
<LineChart xField="Date" yField="EUR" data={[
  {Date:"22.2.2022", EUR:231}
  {Date:"23.2.2022", EUR:142}
  {Date:"24.2.2022", EUR:152}
]} />
```

Now, the keys of the objects in the `data` array should be restricted to be either the value of `xField` or `yField`

```
<LineChart xField="Date" yField="EUR" data={[
  {Date:"22.2.2022", EURO:231} // Compile error since "EURO" is not a valid key
  {Date:"23.2.2022", EURO:142}
  {Date:"24.2.2022", EURO:152}
]} />

<LineChart xField="Date" yField="EUR" data={[
  {Date:"22.2.2022", EUR:231} // No compile error, EUR is a valid key since yField = "EUR"
  {Date:"23.2.2022", EUR:142}
  {Date:"24.2.2022", EUR:152}
]} />
```

How can I modify the `Props` of my `Linechart` component to match this behavior? Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

My Linechart component looks like the following

```
export default function LineChart({ data, xField, yField }: Props) {
  const config: LineConfig = {
    data,
    xField,
    yField,
    slider: {
      start: 0.1,
      end: 0.5,
    },
  };

  return <Line {...config} style={{ gridRow: "2/4", gridColumn: "2/8" }} />;
}
```

Comment: You are defning `data` as an object with `x` and `y` attributes but in the example you pass `Date` and `EURO` instead.

Comment: @Camilo I know. `x` and `y` should somehow be forced to be equal to `xField` and `yField` respectively, if that makes sense? Or maybe I'm doing something funamentally wrong here

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to achieve, why would you define `data` as having the `x` and `y` attributes if you are going to pass `Date` and `EURO`?

Comment: I think I didn't communicate my question properly. I will try to reformulate it.

Comment: @Camilo Question updated. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Post your code for `LineChart`

Comment: @possum Here you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics for handling this. Set a type for the `x` and `y` which extends string. Then, use that type as keys for the data array.

```
interface Props<X extends string, Y extends string> {
  x: X;
  y: Y;
  data: Array<{ [k in X | Y]: k extends X ? string : number }>;
}

function MyComponent<X extends string, Y extends string>(
  props: Props<X, Y>
): JSX.Element {
  return <div />;
}

function MyComponent2() {
  return (
    <MyComponent
      x="Date"
      y="Eur"
      data={[
        { Date: '20-10-2022', Eur: 1 },
        { Date: '20-10-2022', Eur: 1 },
        { Date: '20-10-2022', Eur: 1 },
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```